# Number of steps in the training of each stage of the haar cascade is very high (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I trained a cascade classifier with OpenCV, but for each stage it didn't reach the suitable False Alarm Rate. A part from the training process is shown below:

```
    ===== TRAINING 7-stage =====
    <BEGIN
    POS count : consumed   13737 : 13749
    NEG count : acceptanceRatio    34344 : 0.44846
Precalculation time: 4
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   4|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   5|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   6|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   7|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   8|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   9|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|  10|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|  11|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|  12|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|  13|        1| 0.999971|
+----+---------+---------+
|  14|        1| 0.999971|
+----+---------+---------+
|  15|        1| 0.999971|
+----+---------+---------+
|  16|        1| 0.999971|
+----+---------+---------+
|  17|        1| 0.999971|
+----+---------+---------+
|  18|        1| 0.999971|
+----+---------+---------+
|  19|        1| 0.999971|
+----+---------+---------+
|  20|        1| 0.999942|
+----+---------+---------+
|  21|        1| 0.999942|
+----+---------+---------+
|  22|        1| 0.999942|
+----+---------+---------+
|  23|        1| 0.999942|
+----+---------+---------+
|  24|        1| 0.999825|
+----+---------+---------+
|  25|        1| 0.999825|
+----+---------+---------+
|  26|        1| 0.999738|
+----+---------+---------+
|  27|        1| 0.999767|
+----+---------+---------+
|  28|        1| 0.999621|
+----+---------+---------+
|  29|        1| 0.999709|
+----+---------+---------+
|  30|        1| 0.999592|
+----+---------+---------+
|  31|        1| 0.999738|
+----+---------+---------+
|  32|        1| 0.999534|
+----+---------+---------+
|  33|        1| 0.999592|
+----+---------+---------+
|  34|        1| 0.999418|
+----+---------+---------+
|  35|        1| 0.999418|
+----+---------+---------+
|  36|        1| 0.999272|
+----+---------+---------+
|  37|        1|  0.99933|
+----+---------+---------+
|  38|        1| 0.999185|
+----+---------+---------+
|  39|        1| 0.999359|
+----+---------+---------+
|  40|        1| 0.998981|
+----+---------+---------+
|  41|        1| 0.999243|
+----+---------+---------+
|  42|        1| 0.998923|
+----+---------+---------+
|  43|        1|  0.99901|
+----+---------+---------+
|  44|        1|  0.99869|
+----+---------+---------+
|  45|        1| 0.998952|
+----+---------+---------+
|  46|        1| 0.998631|
+----+---------+---------+
|  47|        1| 0.998864|
+----+---------+---------+
|  48|        1| 0.998457|
+----+---------+---------+
|  49|        1| 0.998631|
+----+---------+---------+
|  50|        1| 0.997962|
+----+---------+---------+
|  51|        1| 0.998166|
+----+---------+---------+
|  52|        1| 0.997496|
+----+---------+---------+
|  53|        1| 0.997845|
+----+---------+---------+
|  54|        1| 0.997292|
+----+---------+---------+
|  55|        1| 0.997642|
+----+---------+---------+
|  56|        1| 0.996914|
+----+---------+---------+
|  57|        1| 0.997176|
+----+---------+---------+
|  58|        1| 0.996389|
+----+---------+---------+
|  59|        1| 0.996768|
+----+---------+---------+
|  60|        1| 0.995836|
+----+---------+---------+
|  61|        1| 0.996273|
+----+---------+---------+
|  62|        1| 0.995749|
+----+---------+---------+
|  63|        1|  0.99604|
+----+---------+---------+
|  64|        1| 0.995458|
+----+---------+---------+
|  65|        1| 0.995982|
+----+---------+---------+
|  66|        1|  0.99473|
+----+---------+---------+
|  67|        1| 0.995196|
+----+---------+---------+
|  68|        1| 0.994089|
+----+---------+---------+
|  69|        1| 0.994672|
+----+---------+---------+
|  70|        1| 0.993216|
+----+---------+---------+
|  71|        1| 0.994089|
+----+---------+---------+
|  72|        1| 0.992633|
+----+---------+---------+
|  73|        1| 0.993565|
+----+---------+---------+
|  74|        1| 0.991789|
+----+---------+---------+
|  75|        1| 0.992866|
+----+---------+---------+
|  76|        1| 0.991119|
+----+---------+---------+
|  77|        1| 0.991964|
+----+---------+---------+
|  78|        1| 0.990217|
+----+---------+---------+
|  79|        1| 0.991673|
+----+---------+---------+
|  80|        1| 0.989867|
+----+---------+---------+
|  81|        1| 0.990886|
+----+---------+---------+
|  82|        1| 0.988178|
+----+---------+---------+
|  83|        1| 0.989372|
+----+---------+---------+
|  84|        1| 0.987218|
+----+---------+---------+
|  85|        1| 0.988499|
+----+---------+---------+
|  86|        1| 0.985936|
+----+---------+---------+
|  87|        1| 0.987509|
+----+---------+---------+
|  88|        1| 0.984888|
+----+---------+---------+
|  89|        1|  0.98681|
+----+---------+---------+
|  90|        1|  0.98352|
+----+---------+---------+
|  91|        1| 0.985762|
+----+---------+---------+
|  92|        1| 0.981918|
+----+---------+---------+
|  93|        1|  0.98451|
+----+---------+---------+
|  94|        1| 0.980259|
+----+---------+---------+
|  95|        1| 0.982879|
+----+---------+---------+
|  96|        1| 0.978308|
+----+---------+---------+
|  97|        1| 0.981249|
+----+---------+---------+
|  98|        1| 0.976532|
+----+---------+---------+
|  99|        1| 0.979647|
+----+---------+---------+
| 100|        1| 0.975862|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 8 minutes 41 seconds.
```

About 2000 of samples are the real world samples and others are created by opencv_createsample tools. I don't know exactly what is the problem. I guess the augmented images is very hard for discrimination, is it true?

Comment: can you add some samples to your posting? Which parameters did you choose for augmention?

Comment: which minimum hit rate did you choose?

Comment: the minimum hit rate is 0.99, for the augmentation I just used y angle =0.5 x angle = 0.5 and z angle = 1.1

Comment: did you try 0.95 minHitrate? Did you try without any rotation augmentation or at least with much less? please respect that the angles are given in radian. For most kind of objects I would not assume a cascade classifier to detect objects rotated more than a few degrees. You can output the createsamples' images to check whether your 3d rotation angles still make sense or whether rotating a flat image to 3d might be too much.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. Another issue that I have is that if we add more backgrounds results will be better? Is it possible to have declining in accuracy with increasing number of backgrounds?

Comment: I changed them to 0.1 0.1 and 0.5, but no improvement.

Comment: can you post some sample images you use for training? Does it work if you dont use augmentation at all?

Comment: I run it again, this time I matched the window size of the create_samples and training, now it works, thanks in advance.